# Pandas Dataframe indexing error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

There is an odd behavior when I try to get the index of a dataframe.

Let us consider following dataframe:

IN:

```
data['commodity']
```

---

OUT:

```
                            price  max  maxperstep
    Site  Commodity Type
    Mid   Biomass   Stock     6.0  inf         inf
          CO2       Env       0.0  inf         inf
          Coal      Stock     7.0  inf         inf
          Elec      Demand    NaN  NaN         NaN
          Gas       Stock    27.0  inf         inf
          Hydro     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Lignite   Stock     4.0  inf         inf
          Slack     Stock   999.0  inf         inf
          Solar     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Wind      SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
    North Biomass   Stock     6.0  inf         inf
          CO2       Env       0.0  inf         inf
          Coal      Stock     7.0  inf         inf
          Elec      Demand    NaN  NaN         NaN
          Gas       Stock    27.0  inf         inf
          Hydro     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Lignite   Stock     4.0  inf         inf
          Slack     Stock   999.0  inf         inf
          Solar     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Wind      SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
    South Biomass   Stock     6.0  inf         inf
          CO2       Env       0.0  inf         inf
          Coal      Stock     7.0  inf         inf
          Elec      Demand    NaN  NaN         NaN
          Gas       Stock    27.0  inf         inf
          Hydro     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Lignite   Stock     4.0  inf         inf
          Slack     Stock   999.0  inf         inf
          Solar     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
          Wind      SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
```

Select the index='Mid'

IN:

```
m.commodity = data['commodity'].loc[['Mid']]
```

---

OUT:

```
                       price  max  maxperstep
Site Commodity Type
Mid  Biomass   Stock     6.0  inf         inf
     CO2       Env       0.0  inf         inf
     Coal      Stock     7.0  inf         inf
     Elec      Demand    NaN  NaN         NaN
     Gas       Stock    27.0  inf         inf
     Hydro     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
     Lignite   Stock     4.0  inf         inf
     Slack     Stock   999.0  inf         inf
     Solar     SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
     Wind      SupIm     NaN  NaN         NaN
```

So far everything works perfectly. But there is an odd behavior, when I try to get the index of m.commodity, which is a part of the data['commodity'], I am assuming to get an index level = ['Mid']. Not like the following (South and North are not wanted):

IN:

```
m.commodity.index
```

OUT:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Mid', 'North', 'South'], ['Biomass', 'CO2', 'Coal', 'Elec', 'Gas', 'Hydro', 'Lignite', 'Slack', 'Solar', 'Wind'], ['Demand', 'Env', 'Stock', 'SupIm']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]],
           names=['Site', 'Commodity', 'Type'])
```

Is there a way to fix this? or what am I doing wrong?

**Expected OUTCOME:**

IN:

```
m.commodity.index
```

OUT:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Mid'], ['Biomass', 'CO2', 'Coal', 'Elec', 'Gas', 'Hydro', 
                  'Lignite', 'Slack', 'Solar', 'Wind'], ['Demand', 'Env', 'Stock', 'SupIm']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]],
           names=['Site', 'Commodity', 'Type'])
```

Comment: Reason for this could be, that the program somehow decides to get the index of data['commodity'] instead of m.commodity.

Comment: So, do you want Mid appearing multiple times? Or just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Edited by Icedkk:

Turns out, this behavior of pandas is common and is a bug mentioned in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7614 , https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2770 , and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12822

.remove_unused_levels() is somehow only way to fix this unusual behavior.

---

You need [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) and assign back:

```
m.commodity.index = m.commodity.index.remove_unused_levels()
print (m.commodity.index)

MultiIndex(levels=[['Mid'], ['Biomass', 'CO2', 'Coal', 'Elec', 'Gas', 'Hydro', 
                  'Lignite', 'Slack', 'Solar', 'Wind'], ['Demand', 'Env', 'Stock', 'SupIm']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]],
           names=['Site', 'Commodity', 'Type'])
```

And for check first level:

```
print (m.commodity.index.remove_unused_levels().levels[0])

Index(['Mid'], dtype='object', name='Site')
```

Comment: Optimal would be not removing the labels, but creating the labels only with 'Mid', why does it even get the levels of 'North' and 'South'. They are not in m.commodity dataframe. By the way your output is what I am looking for, but without removing any levels.

Comment: Well if you do this 'm.commodity.index=m.commodity.index.remove_unused_levels()', it is going to work. But why is it even creating the multiindex with 'South' and 'North'?

Comment: It was long term bug, resolved in pandas `0.20.0+ pandas version` this function.

Comment: I got pandas (0.20.1), so it should not be the case.

Comment: Yes, I only explain why there are `'South',  'North'`, reason is bug and solution is `remove_unused_levels()` for remove all labels and levels what are not visible in datafarme, but are visible if check `m.commodity.index`

Comment: Oh I see, so there is no real solution for this. Okey mate thank you :)

Comment: I dont understand why my solution is not what you need. Something missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161542/discussion-between-icedkk-and-jezrael).